# Checked Exception is compile time or runtime?

Tags: java, exception

I read about Checked exception that it is checked by compiler , but its runtime only.

Is it correct?

If it is correct then how?

Comment: No exception can be thrown at compile time. Your question is not clear

Comment: I agree to your point that No exception can be thrown at compile time . How checked exception is runtime, can you please explain me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checked exceptions are checked at compile time to ensure you are handling them, either by catching them or declaring the containing method `throws` the exception.

At runtime, there is no distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions: they are treated identically by the JVM. So "checked-ness" is purely a compile-time concept.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime exceptions are not checked exceptions. Checked exceptions are the class `Exception` and all subclasses except for `RuntimeException`.

Checked exceptions need to be either handled in your code or declared in the method's signature otherwise your code won't compile. Runtime exceptions do not need to be handled or declared.

Comment: I asked something else you answered something else